# How do I pass the parameter value of a function in one component to another component

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to take the parameter value of a function in one component to another component.

**list-consultation.component.html**

```
<div class="col">
<div class="card type-card"  [routerLink]="['/consultation/type']" (click)="OnMatCardClickEvent('Individual Career Counseling Sessions')">

  <img
    src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/city/041.webp"
    class="card-img-top"
    alt="..."
  />
  <div class="card-body">
    <h2 class="card-title">Individual Career Counseling Sessions</h2>
    <p class="card-text">
      This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to
      additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are different cards with different names and all cards routes to the same page. So I need to change the topic of the second page accordingly. Therefore, I need to send the title of the card to the other page. Here I used `OnMatCardClickEvent`with string parameter.

**list-consultation.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ConsultationService } from 'src/app/services/consultation.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-consultation',
  templateUrl: './list-consultation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-consultation.component.css'],
})
export class ListConsultationComponent implements OnInit {
  listConsultants: any;
  router: any;
  constructor(private consultationService: ConsultationService) {}
  type = '';
  OnMatCardClickEvent(clicked_id: string) {
    this.type = clicked_id;
    console.log(this.type);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.consultationService.listConsultants().subscribe((data) => {
      this.listConsultants = data;
      console.log(this.listConsultants);
    });
  }
}
```

Next Component **request-consultation.component.html**

```
<div>
  <h1>{{ type }}</h1>
</div>

<mat-card class="form-card">
  <mat-card-title>Consultation Request</mat-card-title><br />
  <mat-card-content>
    <form [formGroup]="requestConsultationForm" (submit)="sendRequest()">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Undergraduate Email</mat-label>
        <input type="text" matInput formControlName="undergraduate_email" />
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
          <mat-option>None</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
      <button
       mat-raised-button
       color="primary"
       [disabled]="!requestConsultationForm.valid"
      >
       Send Request
     </button>
   </form>
 </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

**request-consultation.component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ConsultationService } from 'src/app/services/consultation.service';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-request-consultation',
  templateUrl: './request-consultation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./request-consultation.component.css']
})
export class RequestConsultationComponent implements OnInit {
  requestConsultationForm: FormGroup =new FormGroup({});
  selected: String = '';
  @Input() type: string | undefined;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private consultationService: ConsultationService, 
    private router: Router,
    private  _snackBar: MatSnackBar, 
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.requestConsultationForm=this.formBuilder.group({
      'undergraduate_email': new FormControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.email])
    })
  }
}
```

I tried to use @Input to do this. But it didn't work. The thing I need to do is to display the parameter value(which passed though `OnMatCardClickEvent` function) in the `request-consultation.component`.

Can you help me to solve this problem please.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple choices for you. You can use `@Output()` with `EventEmitter` to communicate between your `child` and `parent` components. You can also use `Observables` and `Subjects` via a `service` or even `Setters` and `Getters`. If you are to use `Subjects` and `Observables`  be sure to manage your `subscriptions` very well to avoid `memory leaks`. [Read here about `@Output()`](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

Comment: I already tried @output as well. But didn't work. I may be missed something. Thanks for your help. I will try other methods as well.